# PHP sort array with sub arrays

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
Array(
  [0]=Array
  (
    [firstname] => john
    [lastname] => doe
    [age] => 35
    [salary] => Array
      (
        [gbp] => "180"
        [eur] => ""
        [usd] => ""
      )
  )
  [0]=Array
  (
    [firstname] => john
    [lastname] => doe
    [age] => 35
    [salary] => Array
      (
        [gbp] => ""
        [eur] => "180"
        [usd] => ""
      )
  )
  [0]=Array
  (
    [firstname] => john
    [lastname] => doe
    [age] => 35
    [salary] => Array
      (
        [gbp] => ""
        [eur] => ""
        [usd] => "224"
      )
  )
)
```

How can I sort subarrays by values of the nested subarray (by salary) beginning of the highest salary to the lowest salary regardless of the currency in use?

Comment: You'll have to standardize the currency values, probably by picking one currency and translating them all to it.  Then use something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php to sort the array by the sub-index you want.

Comment: By "regardless of the currency in use" you mean that 300 Yen would be more than 299$?

Comment: @EnricoAgrusti I mean i need to make the sort take the currencies into consideration, to convert the values from GBP to EUR and to USD to see which one is bigger

Comment: As it is highly inconvenient to do in the middle of a sorting operation, you'd better follow @Kwahn's advice and convert all salaries first.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is PHP uasort.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

This will allow you to create the custom sorting criteria you need.

Answer (score 0):

here's a class to help you out, there's a `customValue()` function to extract your data and convert it to a common currency (I used 'usd'), obviously this conversion changes daily

```
<?php
class ArrayCustomSort
{
    private $arrCustomValues = [];
    private $arrFieldOrder = [];

    public function setCustomValues(array $arrCustomValues)
    {
        $this->arrCustomValues = $arrCustomValues;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setFieldOrder(array $arrFieldOrder)
    {
        $this->arrFieldOrder = $arrFieldOrder;
        return $this;
    }

    private function customValue($field, $data)
    {
        $value = $data;
        if (is_object($data)) {
            $value = $data->$field;
        } elseif (is_array($data)) {
            $value = $data[$field];
        }

        $result = $value;
        if (array_key_exists($field, $this->arrCustomValues)) {
            $mxdOrder = $this->arrCustomValues[$field];
            if (is_array($mxdOrder) && ($result = array_search($value, $mxdOrder)) === false) {
                $result = count($mxdOrder);
            } elseif (is_string($mxdOrder) && function_exists($mxdOrder)) {
                $result = $mxdOrder($value);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    private function cmp($a, $b)
    {
        $result = 0;
        reset($this->arrFieldOrder);
        while ($result === 0 && list($key, $value) = each($this->arrFieldOrder)) {
            if (is_int($key)) {
                $field = $value;
                $order = SORT_ASC;
            } else {
                $field = $key;
                $order = $value;
            }
            $order = (in_array($order, [SORT_ASC, SORT_DESC])) ? $order : SORT_ASC;

            $aValue = $this->customValue($field, $a);
            $bValue = $this->customValue($field, $b);
            if ($aValue > $bValue) {
                $result = 1;
            } elseif ($aValue < $bValue) {
                $result = -1;
            }
            if ($order === SORT_DESC) {
                $result *= -1;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function arraySort(array &$arrData) {
        usort($arrData, ['self', 'cmp']);
        return $this;
    }
}

$arr = [
  [
    'firstname' => 'john',
    'lastname' => 'doe',
    'age' => 35,
    'salary' => [
        'gbp' => "180",
        'eur' => "",
        'usd' => ""
    ]
  ],
  [
    'firstname' => 'john',
    'lastname' => 'doe',
    'age' => 35,
    'salary' => [
        'gbp' => "",
        'eur' => "180",
        'usd' => ""
    ]
  ],
  [
    'firstname' => 'john',
    'lastname' => 'doe',
    'age' => 35,
    'salary' => [
        'gbp' => "",
        'eur' => "",
        'usd' => "224"
    ]
  ]
];

function customValue($value)
{
    static $arrToUSD = ['gbp' => 1.35, 'eur' => 1.19 , 'usd' => 1.00];
    $result = max([
        (!empty($value['gbp'])) ? $value['gbp'] * $arrToUSD['gbp'] : 0,
        (!empty($value['eur'])) ? $value['eur'] * $arrToUSD['eur'] : 0,
        (!empty($value['usd'])) ? $value['usd'] * $arrToUSD['usd'] : 0
    ]);
    return $result;
}

$objArrayCustomSort = new ArrayCustomSort();

$objArrayCustomSort->setCustomValues([
    'salary' => 'customValue'
]);

$objArrayCustomSort->setFieldOrder([
    'salary' => SORT_DESC
]);

$objArrayCustomSort->arraySort($arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: I tried to run the code and i got A non-numeric value encountered on line (111 - 112 - 113)

Comment: @Ahmed hopefully that should sort it, a problem in the `customValue()` function. oh, and if you have any influence over how the code is structured it might be an idea to change the `salary` array to something like this: `['salary' => ['amount' => 180, 'currency'=> 'gbp]]` - that way you don't have data redundancy and you won't need to make massive updates when you add new currencies

Answer (score 0):

First you need to loop though the arrays and assign a value based on the currencies

```
$sortOrder = [];
foreach ($array as $person) {
    $sortOrder []= getCurrencyValue($person['salary']);
}
```

where getCurrencyValue takes in the array of currencies and returns an int as a sorting order.

The use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

```
array_multisort($originalArray, $sortOrder)
```

this will sort the orginal array in the same order as $sortOrder when that is sorted.

See the docs for more info (look for the volume and edition example, that is close to what you are doing)